# How to flatten nginx buffer chain?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to take an nginx buffer chain and work with it in some experimental code. In order to do so, I need to first flatten the chain into a single block of memory. Here's what I've got so far (actual production code is a bit different, so this is untested):

```
u_char *flatten_chain(ngx_chain_t   *out) {
    off_t       bsize;
    ngx_chain_t *out_ptr;
    u_char      *ret, *ret_ptr;
    uint64_t    flattenSize = 0;

    out_ptr = out;

    while (out_ptr) {
        if(!out_ptr->buf->in_file) {
            bsize = ngx_buf_size(out_ptr->buf);
            flattenSize += bsize;
        }
        out_ptr = out_ptr->next;
    }

    ret = malloc(flattenSize);
    ret_ptr = ret;

    out_ptr = out;

    while (out_ptr) {
        bsize = ngx_buf_size(out_ptr->buf);

        if(!out_ptr->buf->in_file) {
            memcpy(ret_ptr, out_ptr->buf->pos, (size_t)bsize);
            ret_ptr += bsize;
        }
        out_ptr = out_ptr->next;
    }

    return(ret);

}
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. Disclaimer: it's possible that it *does* work and my data is getting corrupted somewhere else... but while I look into that, can someone please confirm or deny that the above *should* work?

Thanks!

Comment: How does it not work? If you check the contents pointed at by `ret` before the function returns by, say, printing them out, are they not what you expect?

Comment: I know you qualified that this is not production code, but you should use `ngx_pcalloc()` instead of `malloc()` if possible, and give it the request's `pool` member. This way the memory is automatically freed by Nginx when the request is done being handled.